# Disable nav tabs based on status

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this bootstrap nav tab.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
   <div class="breadcrumb">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#submitted" data-toggle="tab">Submitted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pendingApproval" data-toggle="tab">Pending Approval</a></li>
          <li><a href="#workInProgress" data-toggle="tab">Work In Progress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab">Complete</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content" style="margin:5%;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="submitted" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='submitted'}">
         Submitted data will be displayed here....
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="pendingApproval" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='pending'}">
        Pending Approvals will be displayed here....
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="workInProgress" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='inprogress'}">
         In Progress data will be displayed here....
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="complete" ng-class="{'active':dataStatus=='completed'}">
         Completed data will be displayed here....
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here I am getting different status in `dataStatus` variable,based on that am adding active class to a tab.

My Query is If I get `pending` in `dataStatus` ,tabs should be disabled after `pending tab` I can access `submitted and pending tab`.I should can access `in progress and completed` tab.

Same as all status. I should access only the previous tabs based on status.how can I do it?Any help?Thanks!!

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/70Luf7hu/76/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a separate class for disabling the li element and add conditions/expressions as per your requirement in the ng-class. Below is the jsfiddle link

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anilsarkar/9xf5neyz/17/

```
.disabled {
pointer-events:none; 
opacity:0.6;
```

}

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#submitted" data-toggle="tab">Submitted</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'disabled':dataStatus=='submitted'}"><a href="#pendingApproval" data-toggle="tab">Pending Approval</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'disabled':dataStatus=='submitted' || dataStatus=='pending'}"><a href="#workInProgress" data-toggle="tab">Work In Progress</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'disabled':dataStatus=='submitted' || dataStatus=='pending' || dataStatus=='inprogress'}"><a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab">Complete</a></li>
   </ul>
```

**Note: I have added a disabled class to disable the li element**

Comment: working fine.Is there any other shortcut instead of writing in each tab?

Comment: Am already using one ng-class to enable and disable `active` class.Can I use one more ng-class here now?

Comment: Yes you can. You will have to write ng-class in each tab, i don't see any other shortcut.